# Why is jython slow?

Tags: java, python, performance, jython

Jython performance is generally critized as slow --- is there a particular reason for this?  Or is this just a modern myth? And most importantly, what is the future of Jython and how aggressively is it being developed?  Will the ability to script in python against the JVM ever be performant enough for mainstream usage?

Comment: Because java is slow?

Comment: Two words: Duck. Typing.

Comment: By slow I think the criticism is that the compiled Jython code is slower than Java code with equal functionality, but part of that is probably due to the implementation of Jython. It's been years since I touched Jython, but I remember development of it being slow, lagging far behind CPython releases. The nature of Python is probably also part of it, as it definitely allows more than you can do in Java (like SK-logic mentions duck typing).

Comment: @birryree: The JVM was designed for the Java language... may be something is just impossible to get as fast as it is in CPython (I'm for example thinking to basic integer arithmetic that in Python has arbitrary precision).

Answer (score 8):

Jython 2.5.2 was released in March and featured as part of its release notes [2.5.2 Release Notes](http://www.jython.org/latest.html) some performance gains that it 2.5.2 runs the richards benchmark 3x faster and the pystone benchmark 20% faster than 2.5.1.

Here is a recent benchmark of jython 2.5.2 running on jvm 7 where jython is slower than Pypy but faster than Cpython. Take from it what you will [Benchmarks](http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.com/2011/08/performance-gains-in-jython-252.html)

Its at the point where it's more than viable to be using and there are some new cool projects like [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) that demonstrate its power.

I searched for recent speed comparisons with Jruby but didn't find anymore recent comparisons than 2008/2009.